# query on xml data type in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have this structure in my sql server :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<HydroResultTestParameterView xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ReceptionId>11</ReceptionId>
  <CapsuleCompany>BR</CapsuleCompany>
  <CapsuleSerialNumber>228154</CapsuleSerialNumber>
  <CapsuleType>1</CapsuleType>
  <CapsuleBuiltDate>1389</CapsuleBuiltDate>
  <CapsuleExpireDate>1405</CapsuleExpireDate>
  <GasSystemGeneration>1</GasSystemGeneration>
  <Remark>ok</Remark>
</HydroResultTestParameterView>
```

My datatype of my column in nvarchar(max).So i want to get all of `ReceptionId` result that  has `CapsuleCompany=BR` .How can i find these result ?

Comment: Please include in your question the expected output based on your input.

Comment: @TT. All receptionID with CapsuleCompany=BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This explicitely selects all nodes using a XPath expression, taking all `HydroResultTestParameterView` with a sub-element `CapsuleCompany` with text = "BR": `/HydroResultTestParameterView[CapsuleCompany="BR"]/ReceptionId`

```sql
DECLARE @t TABLE(x XML);
INSERT INTO @t(x)VALUES(N'<HydroResultTestParameterView xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ReceptionId>11</ReceptionId>
  <CapsuleCompany>BR</CapsuleCompany>
  <CapsuleSerialNumber>228154</CapsuleSerialNumber>
  <CapsuleType>1</CapsuleType>
  <CapsuleBuiltDate>1389</CapsuleBuiltDate>
  <CapsuleExpireDate>1405</CapsuleExpireDate>
  <GasSystemGeneration>1</GasSystemGeneration>
  <Remark>ok</Remark>
</HydroResultTestParameterView>');

SELECT
    n.v.value('.[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM
    @t
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/HydroResultTestParameterView[CapsuleCompany="BR"]/ReceptionId') AS n(v)
```

Comment: Thank you ,My table structure in database is like this :SELECT id,
      [Result]
      
  FROM [S].[dbo].[HydrostaticTests],And the xmldata is    [Result],how can i change your query to bind the xml to my table ?

Comment: something like this :
  SELECT
    convert(xml,ResultTest) as x
FROM
  [S].[dbo].[HydrostaticTests]
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/HydroResultTestParameterView[CapsuleCompany="BR"]/ReceptionId') AS n(v)

Comment: But i get this error :Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'x'.
Msg 9506, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Apparantly you worked it out yourself, I wasn't around when you asked the followup questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 convert(xml,ResultTest).query('/HydroResultTestParameterView/CapsuleSerialNumber')

FROM
  [S].[dbo].[HydrostaticTests]
WHERE
   convert(xml,ResultTest).exist('/HydroResultTestParameterView[CapsuleSerialNumber="47274"]') = 1;


//-----------------

SELECT
 convert(xml,ResultTest).value('(/HydroResultTestParameterView/CapsuleSerialNumber)[1]', 'int')

FROM
  [S].[dbo].[HydrostaticTests]
WHERE
   convert(xml,ResultTest).exist('/HydroResultTestParameterView[CapsuleSerialNumber="47274"]') = 1;
```

Comment: Using `exist` would work as well. What I described in my answer uses `CROSS APPLY`; that will filter out rows that do not have a result from the `nodes` function. The XPath explicitly selects only `​ReceptionId` elements that are children of a `HydroResultTestParameterView` element having a `CapsuleCompany` element with text `BR`.